# Lost my PGP private key, Is the backup on keyserver the samething?

Tags: pgp

I can find the key I created and backed up to the key server. Can I import that key on the server and use it as my default key? No idea where my back up went, I must have ate it. So I guess simply asking. Is the key I backed up to the key server the same as the missing backup? Can I import it to GNU and use my passphrase that I DO remember and that be my key?

Comment: One thing you should remember for the next time is SET AN EXPIRY DATE for your key. This way it will just expire if lost... someday.

Answer (score 6):

A key server does not provide backups. The task of the key server is to make it possible to find the *public* keys of others, which means only the public keys gets published.

Comment: @michael-grady-sr You may want to log back in and mark this answer as the one that solved your problem.  It will provide @steffen with some extra karma, but more importantly, if / when comments are hidden because theres a lot of them or they're old, marking this answer as the "correct" one will show other uses on the site that you thought this one was correct.  According to [What Should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  ```To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.```

Answer (score 0):

A code lock uses the same code for opening and closing. PGP doesn't, it's what you's call assymetric encryption. This means you can publish one key, and others can use it as a padlock which only you can open with your matching private key. For situations like this, you'd generate a revocation certificate beforehand to retract your key if lost or stolen.

Answer (score 0):

PGP utilizes Public-Private Key Cryptography, you distribute the public key, and you safe guard the private key at all costs. Your private key is never sent anywhere unless you send it there. This means that if you lose your private key the messages are lost forever. There is no 'key recovery' option other than backups that you have made. Also you should never trust anyone else to "store" your private key for you, it's a bad idea, and it could end up in a compromise of your information's security. In the future remember to keep a backup of your private key somewhere maybe on a USB drive dedicated to the task, never used, except to restore the key. And sorry that I couldn't be of more assistance.